# Replace symbol "%" with word "Percent"

Tags: regex, special-characters

How to replace symbol "%" with a word "Percent".

My original string is "Internal (%) External (%)".
The string should be "Internal (Percent) External (Percent)"

Using regular expression, how I can replace this symbol?

Thanks in advance.
Atul

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a Regex here, you can use a regular replace. For example using .net:

```
string s = "Internal (%) External (%)";
s = s.Replace("%", "Percent");
```

Comment: Whether or not a regex is required is dependent upon the environment, which is presently unspecified. In Javascript, for example, a regex is required if ALL occurrences need replacing.

Answer (score 10):

the match string will simply be a percent symbol: %

However, implementing is specific to your regex environment.

Javascript

```
var myString = "Internal (%) External (%)";
myString = myString.replace(/%/g,"Percent");
```

Comment: `%` does not have a special meaning and should not be escaped. Using JavaScript, `/%/` will work for the first character, make sure to add the `g` flag - `/%/g`

Comment: @Kobi You're right, I don't need to escape it. Beat you to it with the global flag though. ;)

Answer (score 5):

What language are you using?  In many languages, you wouldn't need a regex for this, e.g., in Python...:

```
>>> "Internal (%) External (%)".replace('%','Percent')
'Internal (Percent) External (Percent)'
```

but if you did want to use RE for some peculiar reason, that would also be easy:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('%', 'Percent', "Internal (%) External (%)")
'Internal (Percent) External (Percent)'
```

the details of performing such a global replacement, with REs or without them, will vary by language, so it's hard to offer specific help without knowing what language you're using!-)

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can just use the % symbol it doesn't need to be escaped.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("%", "Percent");
```

Or if like me converting so % could be rendered correctly as HTML

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("%", "&#37;");
```