# java find and replace %

Tags: java, string, replaceall

In java 1.8.0
I am trying to replace %, but it is not matching

```
  String str = "%28Sample text%29";

  str.replaceAll("%29", "\\)");

  str.replaceAll("%28", "\\(");
  System.out.println("Replaced string is " + str);
```

I have tried all this [Replace symbol "%" with word "Percent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796720/replace-symbol-with-word-percent) Nothing worked for me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use `replace` if you don't actually need to match a regex.

Comment: `replaceAll` will not make any changes to the original `String` object. Instead, the result will be returned as a new `String` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working.
You need re-assign to `str`

```
  str = str.replaceAll("%29", "\\)");

  str = str.replaceAll("%28", "\\(");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jerry06's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46824578/4391450) is correct.

But you could do this simply by using `URLDecoder` to decode those unicode value.

```
String s = "%28Hello World!%29";
s = URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s);
```

Will output :

> (Hello World!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you misunderstood the usage of `replaceall`. It's for regex based replacements. What you need to use is the normal `replace` method like that:

```
String str = "%28Sample text%29";

str=str.replace("%29", "\\)"). replace("%28", "\\(");
System.out.println("Replaced string is " + str);
```